# How to get the object that calls a function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, oop, object

PHP provides the function `get_class()`, which does not require a parameter, if it is called in a class context.

I want to write a similar function that is able to **retrieve the calling object without explicitly passing it**. I tried using `debug_backtrace()`, but index `object` is not set:

```
function outer_function() {
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}

class ExampleObject {
    function __construct() {
        outer_function();
    }
}

new ExampleObject();
```

[eval on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/I7ffr)

Please note that it's not relevant wether the function is called from the constructor or not; `get_class()` works also, if it is being called within the constructor.

Comment: Is this from within a member function, because if so, `$this` should work fine.

Comment: @Ben No, `a()` is not a member of class `A`. Maybe I should edit the code to prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: Hi what do you mean with the object? The class of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
function get_caller(): ?object
{
    foreach (debug_backtrace() as $call) {
        if (isset($call['object'])) {
            return $call['object'];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here is [the demo](https://3v4l.org/6WG9i).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
 public function trace($offset = 0)
 {
    $trace = debug_backtrace(false);
    foreach ($trace as $t) {
        // print_r($t);
        // print_r($offset);
        if ($t['file'] != __FILE__) {
            break;
        }

        ++$offset;
    }
    $arr = array_slice($trace, ($offset - count($trace)));
    return $arr;
}
```

This is from a debugging package I wrote,

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Debug

Or you can get it with composer

```
evo/debug
```

This part just returns the piece of the back trace from where it was called.

It works as long as the call is no in the same file.